# Bug : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

i am getting this error on line by line validation.can any one help me.............?

Comment: You need to at least post the line that you're getting this error on. Preferably, you should post the entire method containing the line.

Comment: Set the object reference with an object.

Comment: It means your variable is not initialized (you ask the value before setting it), but we need a code example to really help you.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me. I wonder why there are only 2 close votes.

Comment: Please post the Stack Trace of the exception

Comment: _"I lost my cat. Do you know where it is? Please help..."_ -- Daniel, please understand that we can't help you without at least *some* concrete details to go by. Code would help *a lot*.

Comment: "my car isn't working, whats the problem" - reminds me of a first line support guys job. *cringe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you're trying to dereference a null reference. Something like this:

```
string text = null;
int length = text.Length;
```

Without seeing any code, it's impossible for us to advise you any further. Basically, find out which reference is null and work out how to handle it or prevent it occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an uninitialized variable in your code.

Make sure all variables are initialized before using them:

```
string x = null;
x.Replace(' ', 'x'); // Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

string y = "This is a test";
y.Replace(' ', 'x'); // No problem, y = "Thisxisxaxtest"
```

Comment: There's no such concept as an "uninstantiated" variable. If you mean "uninitialized" variable or "unassigned" variable, then that's incorrect - because a variable can easily be definitely assigned with the value null.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - thanks for the correction. Answer updated.

Comment: If `x` in your code is a local variable, your code won't compile.